# Can I turn off the "Some iCloud data isn't syncing" notification?

Tags: icloud, sonoma

[image: system settings notification]

Yes, this pic is not a notification. I do get a notification, I just didn't grab a screenshot of that.

This is a work computer so I don't need my iCloud data on here. In addition one of the machines it's asking about is one that's been turned in to the company and wiped. I don't remember the password for it, that was months ago and I've rotated my password twice since then and also there isn't anything on it that I need here on the new machine.

I wouldn't care, but I get this notification once a day. It's just an annoyance. I'd like to be logged in to my Apple account because of the app store though.

Sonoma 14.0

Comment: You don’t have to use the same Apple ID for iCloud and the App Store, nor do you have to be signed in to iCloud at all to use the App Store. Ideally you should keep all personal data off of an employer-issued device, if that’s what you have.

Comment: Can I just disable iCloud?

Comment: Yes, see my edited comment above.